# Responsive Background Image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

I am currently working on a project that involves a background image that needs to be linked specifically to an element within a container div.

The link is: http://idearevolution.ca/clients/jab/

The challenge I am running into is that as I resize my screen the green circle doesn't stay behind the guy. I've run into issues with responsive background images having to work with elements within a contained area in the past, but I've never been happy with my solutions.

The last thing I tried was using Sass to run a loop, adding a media query to update the position every 10 - 20 pixels. I don't like this solution however because of the code bloat it generates.

I am wondering if anyone has run into this issue before and if so, how do you go about resolving it? I've tried a few things but I'm just not happy with any of the solutions.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: What is the piece of code you're trying already? Why do you think it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Semantics would fix this problem best.

The semantics of using an image is this:

> If the Image does not add to the content and explanation of the site,
>   do not use the image.

So, in truth, this image looks like it should only be part of the design.
Therefore, use the CSS3 Feature of [Multiple Backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/).